# Program segfaults when compiled with clang but not gcc

Tags: clang, compiler-flags

**Summary**: When I set the `-mcmodel=large` flag when compiling with clang my application segfaults when accessing thread local storage. This does not happen when compiling with gcc. Is this a bug with clang or something I am doing wrong?

**Details**:

The following code segment crashes when compiled with clang when setting the `-mcmodel` flag, but it runs fine when compiled with gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

__thread int tlsTest;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("&tlsTest is %p\n", &tlsTest);
  tlsTest = argc;
  printf("tlsTest is %d\n", tlsTest);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile with: `clang test.c  -pthread -mcmodel=large` the result is:

```
&tlsTest is 0x7fd24262c6fc
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But with: `gcc test.c -pthread -mcmodel=large` the result is:

```
&tlsTest is 0x7f1cf785c6fc
tlsTest is 1
```

The program also works fine when compiled with: `clang test.c  -pthread`

I read the following [link about mcmodel](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/intel_tools/icc/mergedProjects/copts_cls/common_options/option_mcmodel.htm) but I'm not sure how this relates to the segfault that I've observed.  Note that the problem occurs for `-mcmodel=medium` also, but not for `-mcmodel=small`.

Is this a bug with clang/llvm or is it a different interpretation of the standard or some unimplemented feature?

Also my system is Ubuntu 12.04.  My version of gcc is 4.6.3 and the version of clang/llvm that I tested is a recent snapshot of 3.3 development, and I also tested with clang 3.2.

Comment: I could reproduce it on Ubuntu 13.04, clang 3.3